# Configuration interface VLAN hp switch

Tags: switch, vlan, hp, interface

my company purchased a new switch brand HP and I created two VLANs on it. VLAN 2 is for the ports 47 and 49 that provide access to internet through a fiber cable and other VLAN 1, which is for the remaining ports. The switch has a total of 48 ports and wanted to know if I need to assign an IP to the VLAN2 the option VLAN Interfaces for the VLAN1 was assigned an IP that is the internal network.

Comment: I think you need to explain further. Does the switch connect to a router or firewall on the ports for VLAN 2? Is this a layer-3 switch? Which model? what is the switch configuration?

Answer (score 1):

A layer-2 switch needs only one address for management -- most will not even allow more than one.

As VLAN 2 in your setup is *the internet*, you almost *certainly* **DO NOT** want I live IP address on that VLAN. (1 - it wastes an address, and 2 - you don't need your switch attacked by everything else on the internet.)